# Angular2 How can I use ngIf correctly to show some text only when there's no data from server?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am getting some data from server and using ngFor to show them (It's search feature) but when there's no result, I want to show text saying 'There's no result"

How can I do this?

I tried this so far but this isn't working.

```
 <div *ngIf="teaInfo != '{}'">

        <div class="starter-template text-xs-center">
            <h5 style = "text-align:center">No result</h5>

        </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **ngSwitch** to check data exist and show **default message** if no data available as below:

You can also get below result with help of **IF** statement but advisable to use **Switch** instead of If statement for better performance perspective.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="true">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="teaInfo != null && teaInfo.length>0">
        //Perform operation on data
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
         There's no result                 
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

NgFor is used for an array. So just check

```
*ngIf="teaInfo.length>0"
```